# How to explain a dream like state

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I have this character who after committing a murder, gets up slowly and walk away. 
I want to say that he does the getting up and walking away part in a dream like state of mind (unwittingly or not exactly knowing what he is doing)

Can someone suggest me how to do explain this?

Comment: *sleepwalking*?

Comment: Look up synonyms for "trance".

Comment: If the murder matters, please explain exactly why? Equally, getting up and walking away - unwittingly or not exactly knowing what he is doing - can't be the point. If you can describe the state, not the content, you might get a useful answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a **trance** or a **trance-like state**:

> A trance is a state of mind in which someone seems to be asleep and to have no conscious control over their thoughts or actions, but in which they can see and hear things and respond to commands given by other people. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trance)

Answer (score 2):

"He got up and walked away in a [**daze**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daze)":

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> transitive verb
> **1** : to stupefy especially by a blow : STUN · The first punch *dazed* him. · were *dazed* by his response
>
> — daze *noun*
>
> He flung his bat in a *daze* and made a slow trot around the bases …  —Steve Wulf
>
> He sometimes finds himself so focused on cyberspace that he falls into a kind of computer *daze*, losing all track of time. —Leslie Miller
>
> the fall *dazed* him for a moment, causing him to become disoriented

Answer (score 0):

**Drowsy**, [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drowsy) gives to definitions:

> being in a state between sleeping and being awake
>
> feeling sleepy esp. when it is not the usual time to sleep

Attribution for the first definition: (Definition of “drowsy” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Attribution second definition: (Definition of “drowsy” from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary © Cambridge University Press)

Answer (score -1):

Walked away in a fugue state? Implies that this was very traumatic for him, perhaps to the extent that he has a problem remembering the murder.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue_state

Comment: A person in a fugue state is very clear minded, very un dream-like. Fugue state is characterized by an alternate identity with amnesia of the prior one. Very unlike the trance  or dazed situation the OP is asking about.